# SQL: Delete records based on values in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

Please see my fiddle for the example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1aaea/1

My goal is to delete all vendors that have no migrate values of 'Y'.  So in the case of my fiddle, only vendors B and D should be deleted.  I'm struggling with how to delete all vendors where migrate='n', but keep vendors that have migrate='y' EVEN IF they have values of migrate='n'.

How can I include vendors that have migrate='y' and exclude vendors that don't?

I feel like I am thinking too hard and the answer is right under my nose....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by testing for the condition in a `where` clause:

```
delete from example
    where not exists (select 1
                      from example e2
                      where e2.vendor = example.vendor and
                            e2.migrate = 'Y'
                     );
```

To test this in SQLFiddle, you need to put the `delete` in the left window (the schema window), rather than in the query window.

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Thanks Gordon.